# Update or Retrieve from peculiar field name in MongoDB Atlas database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I am stuck in a unique problem. In my database of MongoDB Atlas, I used java to upload documents. Unknowingly, a field name was set as "Vehicle Type", with space in between. This is how it looks in database

[image]

Since database is huge, what is the best way to  rectify the field name for all documents ?

Also if it is possible, how can I retrieve the data from that field in NodeJS using mongoose? Currently in Mongosh (CLI), the field "Vehicle Type" shows as 'Vehicle Type', which I am unable to use :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can connect via CLI then just do this to update all records:

```
db.collection.update({},{$rename: { "Vehicle Type": "VehicleType" }},{multi:true})
```

Please change the collection to your collection in above command and also above will change field name "Vehicle Type" to "VehicleType"

Doc reference: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/